# PHP line breaks in email form

Tags: php, forms, email, line, break

I am having a problem with an email php form. When the user submits the form the email format doesn't come out right. I want it to be something like this:

Contact form below:
Name:
Surname:
email:
telephone:
message:

Using my code below the message comes from the user but with no line breaks. It comes as a straight line like: Contact form: Name: Surname: email: telephone: message:

```
<?php

$email_message .= "Όνομα: ".clean_string($first_name)."\r\n";

$email_message .= "Επώνυμο: ".clean_string($last_name)."\r\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\r\n";

$email_message .= "Τηλέφωνο: ".clean_string($telephone)."\r\n";

$email_message .= "Μήνυμα: ".clean_string($comments)."\r\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Content-type: text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1253;' . "\r\n" .

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

I found that if I remove the line with the content-type in the header the mail comes styled correctly but the characters are messed up because I am using the Greek alphabet.
If anyone can help me I would appreciate it a lot.
[EDIT] It seems all I needed to do was just use text as content type instead of text-html;

```
'Content-type: text; charset=WINDOWS-1253;' . "\r\n" .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on whether you send the email as plain text or html. if you use plain text you can insert a new line character

```
echo "........" . "\n"
```

or if you use html you can use the `<br>` tag

You set your content-type to text/html. So you need to use `<br>` instead of `"\r\n"`

Comment: such a simple solution! thanks a lot. my code works perfectly now.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct then. Thanks

Comment: Oops, First time using the website sorry. I did now :)